# Can't access directive scope from within controller

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with my AngularJS code.

It seems I can't access my directive scope from my controller.

**The directive**

```
app.directive('PaginatedText', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            text: '='
        },
        controller: 'PaginatedTextController',
        templateUrl: '/frontend/views/paginated-text.html'
    };
})
```

**The controller**

```
app.controller('PaginatedTextController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.page = 1;

    $scope.limit = 200;


    console.log($scope, $scope.text);

}]);
```

**The directive call**

```
<paginated-text text="character.long_description"></paginated-text>
```

**The template**

```
<p>
    {{text}}
    <button>read more</button>
</p>
```

The printed console.log:
[image: console.log]

Any idea why `console.log($scope.text)` print undefined ?

Comment: Use @  symbol for text

Comment: No, using '@' will set $scope.text at "character.long_description". My code code won't be eval that way.

Comment: use bindtocontroller and controllerAs instead of scope

Comment: This is very common when the actual value of a primitive var is set after the controller is initialized. The console deceives you: the `$scope` is printed as a reference. When printed, the `text` is undefined, when you expand the `$scope` in the console, it has been defined. So: `character.long_description` is given the value `'<p>Lorem ipsum...'` *after* the controller is called. Add a watch for its value and take action there to correct your problem.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I understand... Funny console though ! It works great by the way ! Thank you ! Is this clean (I mean not dirty) to do a $watch just for this little change ?

Comment: @LionC thanks for the bypass ! :) I love that way too, which one do I have to use ?

Comment: Sorry for the third post in a row.
The @NikosParaskevopoulos solution suits better in my case.
Thanks to both of you !

Comment: The "i" icon at the end of the first console.log print is precisely for what Nikos has mentioned. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18098661/1235243

Comment: @Bharat I don't even know that "feature" thanks for pointing this out !

Comment: *"Is this clean...to do a $watch just for this little change"*: I feel your worries. If this directive is to be used 10s of times in a view, you may want to consider some other solution. Otherwise I expect the performance hit to be negligible. It may be possible to do the listening in a setter with `Object.defineProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

Directive names must start with lowercase!

```
app.directive('paginatedText',
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.character = {
      long_description: 'LirumLarum'
    };
  })
  .directive('paginatedText', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        text: '='
      },
      controller: 'PaginatedTextController',
      template: '<p>{{text}}<button>read more</button></p>'
    };
  })
  .controller('PaginatedTextController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

      $scope.page = 1;

      $scope.limit = 200;


      console.log($scope, $scope.text);

    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <paginated-text text="character.long_description"></paginated-text>
</div>
```